# Timer that blocks thread between events

Tags: java, timer

Is there a class similar to `java.util.Timer` but uses the thread that started the timer and blocks the thread between events instead of creating a separate thread to dispatch the events?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jtahlborn I am trying to repeat an event every n milliseconds on the EDT until a desired result, but I want to block the thread until it's finished so the GUI is unresponsive.

Comment: If you block the EDT too much, the operating system may mark your app as "failing to respond." This sounds like a bad approach. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @TomG It would only be 1-2 seconds. I'm resizing the window a few times, but I want any modifications to the GUI to happen after it's finished.

Comment: "repeating" an event on the EDT won't do much if you are blocking the EDT thread...?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Thread.sleep()` in a loop.

Comment: The danger there is if the OP wants a constant rate then this becomes a little complicated.